# How to view an executable file with no filetype

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have an application on my raspberry pi with no filetype at the end. When I double click the file it executes it fine but I want to look at the code, and suggestions. Running ls -l in the directory shows me the file is -rwxr-xr-x. what does this mean.

Comment: you could open it with an editor! `-rwxr-xr-x` means that the file is not a directory, (read,write,execute) by the owner, (read,execute) by the group, and (read,execute) by the group by other users https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Representations

Comment: In Linux, the extension has no meaning. Whether a file is executable or not is controlled by the `'x'` (execute, and descend into directory permission). If you look at `ls -al` for each file you will have a leading bit and 3-octets of permissions, e.g. `drwxrwxrwx`. That is `d` for directory or `-` for regular file (or `1`, `2`, `4`, `S`  for special permissions) followed by 3 `rwx` octets specifying what permissions the `owner`, `group` and `world` (everyone else) has.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find out what type of file it is.

That is what `file` command is for, open a terminal and type:

```
file my_executable
```

If it tells you this is some kind of script file, like BASH or Python, right click it, and try to open with an editor, or in the terminal type:

```
nano my_executable
```

But, if the type is ELF, it means this is a binary, and you can not see its source code in the file it self.

You can still try disassembling it with a program like Ghidra, but you would be better off trying to understand where the file came from (did you install it with apt command?) and see if there is source available.

Note that for any free software package you install through:

```
sudo apt-get install my_package
```

You can download the source code with command:

```
apt-get source my_package
```

This does not require `sudo` (it does not change your system), but it will only work for free software / open source packages, which is almost all packages in the default Raspbian repositories.